# Vue Select or Vue multiselect, how to set default value and have it clickable

Tags: vue.js, vue-select

At the moment I only see the placeholder solution. 
I need an option thats already set and visible in the select.

Comment: Doesn't `v-model` on the `select` field do that?

Comment: could you provide a minimum example of what you tried to code? do you want to set e.g. vue multiselect's value to a default, so that one option is already chosen directly?